# svg-React Component can't resize in scss

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, sass

I use svg as React Component. But I can't resize svg width and height in scss

```
import classNames from 'classNames/bind';
import styles from './MainPage.module.scss';
import CustomerIcon from '../../assets/icons/fonts/groups_black_24dp.svg';
import HostIcon from '../../assets/icons/fonts/person_black_24dp.svg';

const cx = classNames.bind(styles);

function MainPage() {
  return (
    <main>
      <div>
        <CustomerIcon className={styles.icon} />
      </div>
   );
};
```

css is

```
.icon{
    display:block;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    fill: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

The fill property works, but width and height are not.

Is it the only way to enter width and height in all svg files?

Answer (score 0):

in the element div, try giving css for full width because in the parent element there is no width and height size, or try moving the classname icons to the element div